# Delete a specific entry by key in a map. std::unordered_map<const char*,std::vector<int>> mp;

Tags: vector, stl, unordered-map

I am doing like this :

auto find = mp.find(key);
if(find != mp.end()) mp.erase(find);

Will the above delete the whole vector as well corresponding to the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to `erase` will destroy both the key and the value for the entry in the map.

So yes, it will destroy the vector as well.